Как восстановить локальное хранилище?
Всем привет, есть сайт на котором можно внести депозит в крипте и на выходе получить ключ, по которому можно этот депозит вывести. Ключи сохраняются в LocalStorage браузера, я по своей наивности думал, что они там и останутся надолго. По итогу они пропали, пытался восстановить файлы через софт, но не понимаю, в каком файле эти данные хранятся. Сумма внушительная, готов делиться с теми, кто поможет. Жду любых идей
